# Accessing a webserver on aws EC2 instance with custom nameservers ?

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-web-services, nameserver, domain-name

I'm trying to run a web server on an Amazon ec2 instance . When I queried it through ELASTIC-IP for instance, it resolved  perfectly, but whenever I tried to do an nslookup or tried to access it via a custom domain name, I was unable to do so. I have already turned off iptables and added the ports into the relevant security groups. The issue I'm trying to solve is how to resolve the domain name using a custom name-server.

When I try to check the domain name via [intodns](http://www.intodns.com/) it resolves perfectly and returned the name of custom name-servers, so how can point the domain name to my instance ??

Answer (score 2):

> So how can point the domain name to my instance ??

The **exact** same way you would point it to any other server, by creating an A record pointing to the public IP address of the server.

Comment: People seem to overthink this on AWS.

Comment: @ceejayoz Agreed. Not only with DNS, either. People seem to think that EC2 instances are "special" somehow, or that they need to be more complicated. Maybe I need to make a blog post about this...

Answer (score 0):

It may make sense to step back and do this through first principles.  You havn't provided the domain name which means we can't look at it and explain, but -

1. Find the root nameservers for the TLD or country TLD.  If, for example you
   are using a domain name like "itsmy.com", then "dig com NS" will provide 
   you with the nameservers you need to look at, similarly if the domain name
   is mycountry.co.tld", dig tld NS will provide the correct nameservers
   for that TLD.
2. Query the appropriate nameserver for further nameservers - in the example
   of mycountry.co.tld, and repeat until you have the final result - for
   example "dig @ip.ad.dr.xx co.tld NS".  Pick one of the returned nameservers
   and repeat "dig @ns.ip.add.rr mycountry.co.tld".  If this does not return
   any nameservers you know the problem lies with the registry entries for
   the domain name, so speak to your registrar.
3. If the last step is successful, look for A records and CNames for the
   server - for example "dig @ns.ip2.add.r www.mycountry.co.nz A" and
   "dig @ns.ip2.add.r www.mycountry.co.nz CNAME".  If neither of these 
   queries return a valid result, the problem is with the nameserver 
   entries.  Check the nameservers you are using match the ones in the
   ns queries, and then update the A record.  (If there is a CNAME record
   you can then repeat process 1 - 3 on the CNAME, but if you don't know
   how they work, avoid CNAMES as they have gotchas".

This process works regardless of whether its an Amazon EC2 server or any other Internet enabled server.  The logic is identical.

Comment: `$ dig example.com +trace` can more or less take the place of your first two steps.